# Is it possible to run PUBG MOBILE on Mac OS?

Tags: emulation, pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

I am facing this big dilemma since many people say they did run PUBG Mobile on a Mac when the official emulator is made for Windows OS.

### What I've tried:

- #### Bluestacks

  I saw many videos on YouTube about being possible to run PUBG Mobile on a Mac OS system, but the fact is that even the latest version of Bluestacks (v4) doesn't provide the option to properly configure the engine to be emulated. So, trying to run the game ends up with a "Your device is not compatible".
- #### Nox emulator

  I also tried this one, but the app doesn't even show up in the playstore. Which gives later on the same message as Bluestacks if downloading the app from a third-party source.
- #### Memu emulator

  Many YouTube videos guarantee that you can run this game perfectly with Memu. But for some reason I did everything as the video said and still wasn't able to run it. The game just never loaded.
- #### Running Tencent Gaming Buddy through Wine

  In my pursuit to finally be able to play the game on my Mac, I even tried to run the official emulator originaly made only for Windows OS through a program called Wine for Mac OS which somehow can run Windows programs directly on Mac, but for sure I need to configure it to run this application and there is not any documentation about how to use Wine for this case.

It's been almost two months of research, but no successful results. I'm starting to believe that it is not possible. Can someone give me any hope? I think this question could be useful for other people too.

My PC specifications:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to run a game not made for your platform on your Mac, the best approach would be to run the game in a [Virtual Machine](https://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/virtual-machine). Interestingly the Android emulators we use are also Virtual Machine, but in your case the emulator in itself is not made for your Mac. So you should try to search for an emulator that is not a modified form of Windows compatible version but originally designed for running on Mac system.

Incase if you can't find a suitable android emulator then you can download a virtual machine software (like [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/in/products/workstation-player.html) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) for Mac. Then run the android OS iso file in it. By android OS, I am referring to Android x86 based [Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/), [Prime OS](https://primeos.in/download/) etc. These are specifically designed for playing games and enable us to do keyboard mapping.

***The best method***:
There is a feature in Mac itself which enables us to run any other operating system. It is called **[Boot camp assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-in/boot-camp)**. It is very similar to dual booting. You can either install Windows in your machine or directly install PhoenixOS / Prime OS. Both of them are available as exe installer (if you decided to install windows in your Mac) as well as iso image (if you chose to just install android os)

Comment: How about Steam Link?